# How to use a pointer to point only at half of an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I'm new to C and pointers, so i have this problem. I want to tell to pointer how much memory it should point to.

```
char * pointer;
char arr[] = "Hello";
pointer = arr;
printf("%s \n", pointer);
```

This pointer will point to whole array, so i will get "Hello" on the screen. My question is how can i make pointer to only get "Hel".

Comment: you need to replicate the string because the C-String required null-terminator.

Comment: The second "half"? That's easy with some pointer arithmetic: `arr + 3`. The first "half"? That's simply not possible, that's now how arrays, memory or the language work.

Comment: Simple answer: You cannot do that, because a `pointer` simply points to the beginning of a string(or something). A length is not included. An alternative would be using [PASCAL strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Pascal_and_C#Strings) whose length could be manipulated in the first byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
char * pointer;
char arr[] = "Hello";
pointer = arr;
pointer[3] = '\0';    // null terminate of string
printf("%s \n", pointer);
```

If you always work with strings, then have a look at [`strlen`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) for getting length of a string. If a string `arr` has length `l`, then you may set `arr[l/2] = '\0'`, so that when you print `arr`, only its first half will be shown.

You may also want to print the last half of your string `arr`? You can use pointer to point to any place you want as the start. Back to your example, you may try:

```
char * pointer;
char arr[] = "Hello";
pointer = arr + 2;  // point to arr[2]
printf("%s \n", pointer);
```

Have a check what you will get.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` has the ability to print less than the full string, using the precision value in the format string. For a fixed number of characters (e.g. 3), it's as simple as

```
printf( "%.3s\n", pointer );
```

For a variable number of characters, use an asterisk for the precision, and pass the length before the pointer

```
int length = 3;
printf( "%.*s\n", length, pointer );
```

Comment: Just because you can print the first 3 characters it doesn't mean the pointer points only to those 3 of them. The Question was =>> `How to use a pointer to point only at half of an array`

Comment: @Michi Yes, the question is unclear. Specifically, a pointer has no intrinsic length associated with it, so pointing at half an array has no meaning. I posted this because of the other two answers (now deleted) that were addressing the *"print a substring"* interpretation of the question. The *"extract a substring"* interpretation has not yet been answered. ZheyuanLi's answer addresses the *"truncate the input string"* interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know what a pointer is so I'll explain.
A pointer **does not** point to a string. It points to a char! Yes, a char. A string in C is really just a set of chars all one after the other in the memory.
A char* pointer points to the **beginning** of a string. The string ends when there is a '\0' (aka null) char. When you `printf("%s",s)`, what printf does is a cycle like this:

```
int i;
for(i=0;1;i++) //infinite cycle
{
    if(s[i]=='\0')
        break;
    printf("%c",s[i]);
}
```

Meaning it will not print a **string** but all the chars in a char array until it finds a null char or it goes into memory space that is not reserved to it (Segmentation fault).

To print just the 1st 3 characters you could do something like this:

```
void printString(char* s,int n)  //n=number of characters you want to print
{
    if(n>strlen(s))
        n=strlen(s);
    else if(n<0)
        return;
    char temp=s[n];   //save the character that is in the n'th position of s (counting since 0) so you can restore it later
    s[n]='\0';   //put a '\0' where you want the printf to stop printing
    printf("%s",s);   //print the string until getting to the '\0' that you just put there
    s[n]=temp;   //restore the character that was there so you don't alter the string
}
```

Also, your declaration of `pointer` is unnecessary because it is pointing to the exact same position as `arr`. You can check this with `printf("%p %p\n",arr,pointer);`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the objective with a small function, say substring.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> // for accessing strlen function

void substring(char* c,int len)
{
    if (len <= strlen(c)){
        *(c+len)='\0';
        printf("%s\n",c);
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry length, %d not allowed\n",len);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char c[]="teststring";
    char* ptr=c;
    substring(ptr,4);  // 4 is where you wish to trim the string.
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. In C++ a built-in function called `substring` is already available which shouldn't be confused with this.
2. When a string is passed to a function like `printf` using a format specifier `%s` the function prints all the characters till it reaches a null character or `\0`. In essence,  to trim a string  `c` to 4 characters means you put `c[4]` to null. Since the count starts from 0, we are actually changing the 5th character though. Hope the example makes it more clear.

Comment: The title said clearly `How to use a pointer to point only at half of an array` How does your Answer give a solution to that?

Comment: @user3386109 : Valid point! I forgot that subtle matter indeed. Also the comparison changes to `<=`. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

How much of the string is printed is controlled by the NULL-character "\0", which C automatically appends to every string. If you wish to print out just a portion, either override a character in the string with a "\0", or use the fwrite function or something similar to write just a few bytes to stdout.